# Read outlook emails with Python and output to .txt file

Tags: python, email, outlook

Here's the situation. I'm new to Python. Still earning syntax and reading books not making any progress. Everyone seems to say that picking a project is the best way to learn, however I have 0 creativity or imagination, and I'm not grasping this stuff easily. So I finally settled on a project, but I may be shooting for the stars here. At my work, I receive automated emails when specific errors are generated when users update their online profiles and for some reason their updates don't hit their accounts on our end. I get anywhere from 10 to 100 emails a day, all with the same subject line, and more or less the same body. The only info unique to each email are the fields updated by the user, like their display name, phone number etc. Here's what the emails look like (I changed some info, i.e. Simpsons references):

```
 From: osb
    Sent: Tuesday, March 17, 2020 8:37:24 PM (UTC+00:00) Monrovia, Reykjavik
    To: Simpson, Homer
    Subject: Profile Update - Username/PMBUN NOT FOUND - Manual Investigation required.

    Service Name: REVENUE_SERVICES

    Alert Summary: Profile Update - Username/PMBUN NOT FOUND - Manual Investigation required.

    Alert Destination: REVENUE_SERVICES/Resources/ALERTS/RevenueServicesSupport

    Severity: warning

    Alert Timestamp: Tue Mar 17 16:37:24 EDT 2020

    Server Name: osb_server2

    Domain Name: city_osb

    Alert Payload:

    <ServiceAlert>
      <soapenv:Body xmlns:ns1="http://simpsons.ca/services/evpub/evTypes" 
    xmlns:SOAPENV="https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/url=http">
    <ns1:ProcessEventRequest>
      <ns1:EventDetails>
        <Event>PROFILE_UPDATE</Event>
        <Mbun>5b1f67a5gb1f5</Mbun>
        <Pmbun>5r4206tg736u8</Pmbun>
        <TimeStamp>2020-03-17T16:37:24-04:00</TimeStamp>
        <Subsystem>mysp</Subsystem>
      </ns1:EventDetails>
      <EventContent>
        <mys:ProfileResponse xmlns:mys="http://simpsons.ca/services/mysp/MySPTypes">
          <Salutation>MISS</Salutation>
          <Firstname>Marge</Firstname>
          <Lastname>Simpson</Lastname>
          <EmailAddress>m.simpson@hotmail.com</EmailAddress>
          <Lang>EN</Lang>
          <Address>
            <Unit/>
            <AddressLine1>742 EVERGREEN TERR</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2/>
            <City>SPRINGFIELD</City>
            <Province>OH</Province>
            <PostalCode>012345</PostalCode>
          </Address>
          <PrimaryTelphone>
            <Number>5551231234</Number>
            <Extension/>
          </PrimaryTelphone>
          <AltTelphone>
            <Number/>
            <Extension/>
          </AltTelphone>
          <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
          <SystemMessage>Success</SystemMessage>
        </mys:ProfileResponse>
      </EventContent>
    </ns1:ProcessEventRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
  <wbt:ContactUpdateResponse xmlns:wbt="http://simpsons.ca/services/revenue/wbTypes">
    <StatusCode>ERR_NOT_FOUND</StatusCode>
    <SystemMessage>CIS UserName/PMBUN Not Found.</SystemMessage>
  </wbt:ContactUpdateResponse>
</ServiceAlert>
```

Right now, I'm opening every email, and logging all the profile info in excel. I can't keep up with the volume, and I wondered if I could build a Python program that would read each unread email, output the contents to a csv file, that I could then open in excel. I've looked for tutorials and videos and there isn't much for outlook. There a few videos for doing something like with gmail but we use Office365 Outlook at work. I could be completely shooting for the stars here, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is Outlook installed in your computer?

Comment: Yes it is installed on my work computer.

Comment: Was there any solution available? I have similar situation